# Spring Boot CORS configuration not working for authentication with '/login'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I am practically new to Spring, although I am familiar with backend development. I am using Spring Security to implement an authentication system, and have successfully been able to, at least when sending requests from the same origin. However, I need to use a ReactJs frontend app to send requests, which means that CORS needs to be enabled in my Security Configurations.

When CORS is disabled in my backend, I get the following error (as expected):

[image]

However, when I do enable CORS with the following configurations (I've tried both):

1, Applying a configuration with default values:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebAuthenticationConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain (HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/customers", "/products").authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll();

        httpSecurity.csrf();

        httpSecurity.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());

        httpSecurity.headers()
        .frameOptions()
        .sameOrigin();

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, true as enabled "
                                         + "from customer "
                                         + "where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role "
                                                + "from customer "
                                                + "where username=?");
    }
}
```

2. Adding a CorsConfigurationSource Bean in my WebAuthenticationConfig class:

```java
...
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
...
```

and changing this

```java
...
httpSecurity.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
...
```

to this

```
httpSecurity.cors();
```

They don't seem to work either. Whenever I send a post request to my `'/login'` route, the CORS error doesn't trigger for the first request, but the server redirects me to `http://localhost:8080/login;jsessionid=<some_cookie_value>` and I get a CORS error on that redirect.

[image]

Also my cookies appear to be empty, so I don't know what that redirect is supposed to do.

I haven't found another recent question where this happens, and no easy fix either. As I mentioned, I am new to Spring and Spring Boot and find them rather confusing, so if I skipped any important details please let me know.

Comment: I'm no Spring expert, but you've likely stacked your filter chain in an incorrect order. In particular, the CORS filter must occur before any authentication filter, since CORS-preflight requests are not themselves authenticated.

Comment: Are you running your Spring Boot app in a servlet container, like Wildfly? I just wonder about the session ID in your redirect URL. Embedded Tomcat doesn't make it by default.

Comment: Show your request with headers. maybe there is a non default header, which have to be allowed.

Comment: As suggested, I tried moving the CORS configuration to the beggining of the function, but I still had the same problem. I was running the application with embedded Tomcat. My request headers (the ones I manually set at least) were: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"' and 'Accept: application/json'. I solved this problem by removing the line `httpSecurity.csrf()`, but I am not sure why, I will look into it. However, one odd thing that I noticed a while after this change, was that cookies were not properly being stored/sent by the browser.

Comment: I guess that issue shoud be discussed on a separate question, so I'll leave it there. Also, I read somewhere that basic authentication isn't recommended, as there were some issues this some browsers' caches. I can't find the source, but will attach it here as soon as I find it.